# Hi i am trying to execute a function in MySQL ... I am unable to get it compiled.... I think I have error in my code .. I think the problem ending if

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to create a function for calculating discount which is linked to coupon in coupons table
Hence I am trying to create a function where it takes Item id , coupoun id, Purchasing amount from coupouns table and campaign id from campaign table
i am trying to check coupons validity for the item being purchased, min amount of purchase required ,
coupon date validity

```
`
```

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION Func_Discount
     (
      Item_Id1 Varchar(32),
      Coupon_Id1 Varchar(32),
      Campaign_Id1 Varchar(32),
      PurchasingAmt1 INT

     )
    RETURNS INT 
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
         DECLARE Item_Id2 Varchar(32);
     DECLARE Coupon_Id2 Varchar(32);
     DECLARE Expiry INT;
     DECLARE Expiry1 INT;
     DECLARE PurchasingAmt2 INT;
     DECLARE CoupounType1 Varchar(32);
     DECLARE Value1 INT;
     DECLARE Discount int;

        SET Coupon_Id2 = (select Coupon_Id from  CouponMapping where Coupon_Id =  Coupon_Id1);
   IF (Coupon_Id2 is NULL)
       THEN
      RETURN 0;

     ELSE
 
           SET Item_Id2 = (select Item_Id from  CouponMapping where Coupon_Id =  Coupon_Id1);
        SET PurchasingAmt2 = (select Min_Purchase from  CouponMapping where Coupon_Id =                           Coupon_Id1);
         SET Expiry = (select DATEDIFF(now(),end_date) from Campaign where campaign_id  =      Campaign_Id1);
         SET Expiry1 = (select Expiry from CouponMapping where Coupon_Id = Coupon_Id1);
        SET CoupounType1 = (select couponType   from CouponMapping where Coupon_Id = Coupon_Id1);
         SET Value1 = (select Value from CouponMapping where Coupon_Id = Coupon_Id1);

        IF (Item_Id2=Item_Id1 AND PurchasingAmt1 >= PurchasingAmt2 AND Expiry<=Expiry1 AND Coupoun_Type1 = "Percent")
   
            THEN

                SET Discount =( (value1 * PurchasingAmt1)/100);

                ELSE IF (Item_Id2=Item_Id1 AND PurchasingAmt1 >= PurchasingAmt2 AND          Expiry<=Expiry1 AND Coupoun_Type1 = "Flat")
                   THEN
                        SET Discount = Value1;
           END IF;
    END IF;

       RETURN Discount; 
  END$$
   DELIMITER ;`
```

Comment: Please publish the error code in full, ps every if needs an end if; You should reread https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: I linked this to an old answer I wrote to the exact same syntax problem — you used `ELSE IF` with the assumption that it was a "ladder" but MySQL doesn't support that.